# Horizontal Recyclerview inside Viewpager android

Tags: android, scroll, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, horizontal-scrolling

I am facing a problem with `Recyclerview` inside `Viewpager` fragments.

I have two fragments and both loaded in `ViewpagerAdapter.` In the second fragment, I have a simple Horizontal `Recyclerview.` Initially, 1st fragment is loaded in `ViewPager` and when I swipe right to left on screen it will redirect me to the second fragment.

In the second fragment `Recyclerview` already loaded. But when I tried to scroll `Recyclerview` horizontally for more items it is not scrolling it redirects me to the 1st fragment from swipe left to right.

**How to allow the user to view more items?**

Help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you enable nested scrolling?

Comment: Overriding the recycler view's on touch event works as mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269842/horizontal-recyclerview-inside-viewpager-is-not-scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable Nested Scrolling for recyclerview

after initialising your recyclerview, add this line of code

```
your_recyclerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
```